# E0405: Submission request doesn't have any application or lib path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-workflow

Its a first time am running mapreduce program from Oozie.

Here is my job.properties file

```
nameNode=file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
jobTracker=localhost:8088
queueName=default
oozie.wf.applications.path=${nameNode}/Config
```

Here is my hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Here is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
 </property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.hduser.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.hduser.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

But when I run Ozzie command to run my Mapreduce program, Its give error that `lib` folder is not found. `Error: E0405 : E0405: Submission request doesn't have any application or lib path`

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
```

I've created `Config` folder in `HDFS` and in that folder created `lib` folder too. In `lib` folder placed my mapreduce jar file and inside `Config` folder placed my `workflow.xml` file. (Its all in HDFS)

I think I ve give wrong HDFS path (`nameNode`) in `job.propertie`s file. That's why its not able to find `{nameNode}/Config`, May I  know please what would be hdfs path ..?

Thanks

Update - 1 job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8088
queueName=default
oozie.wf.applications.path=${nameNode}/Config
```

still getting same error:

```
Error: E0405 : E0405: Submission request doesn't have any application or lib path
```

Update - 2 `workflow.xml` in `Config` folder in HDFS.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="simple-Workflow">
   <start to="RunMapreduceJob" />
   <action name="RunMapreduceJob">
      <map-reduce>
         <job-tracker>localhost:8088</job-tracker>
         <name-node>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</name-node>
         <prepare>
            <delete path="file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode"/>
         </prepare>
         <configuration>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
               <value>default</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
               <value>DataDividerByUser.DataDividerMapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
               <value>DataDividerByUser.DataDividerReducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
               <value>/data</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
               <value>/dataoutput</value>
            </property>
         </configuration>
      </map-reduce>
      <ok to="end" />
      <error to="fail" />
   </action>
   <kill name="fail">
      <message>Mapreduce program Failed</message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<namenode>` tag should not be a file path. It should point to the NameNode of the underlying Hadoop cluster where Oozie has to run the MapReduce job. Your name node should be the value of the fs.default.name from your core-site.xml.

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
```

Also, change the property name ***oozie.wf.applications.path*** to ***oozie.wf.application.path*** (without the s).

Add the property `oozie.use.system.libpath=true` to your properties file.

Source: *Apache Oozie* by Mohammad Kamrul Islam & Aravind Srinivasan

Comment: please check my update...! Still smae error..! Is it correct am not able to access hdfs://localhost:8020 on web browser ..?

Comment: Can I do like this "hdfs://localhost:8020 dfs -ls /Config" .. ?

Comment: Try hdfs://localhost:9000 which is the value of fs.default.name in your core-site.xml

Comment: and oozie.wf.applications.path should point directly to your oozie workflow xml file.

Comment: Just tried what you said...Its giving same error... Am I doing something wrong ..?

Comment: likt this oozie.wf.applications.path=${nameNode}/Config/workflow.xml ?

Comment: Also I just noticed that one of your property names is wrong. It should be oozie.wf.application.path (you have an extra "s" on application). Its value should be the path to your workflow xml file or the directory that contains your workflow xml file.

Comment: Add oozie.use.system.libpath=true to your properties file. If that doesn't work, please make another edit with your current configuration and error so we can review.

Comment: now its worked..Thanks :) ..! But it just creating emtpty directory structure /user/hduser/oozie-hdus..any idea from where its taking this path to be created but not to create my mapreduce output .. ?

Comment: I think you should open a new question since the original error was solved, and because I think your new question needs more detail and probably deserves its own post.

Comment: last question grantler..am able to run mapreduce job..but in oozie its  status is stuck at running state ..! May I know what Should check or do ...? why its happening ..?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. There could be another configuration issue somewhere. Check that you have enough cluster resources. Check to see if you have a runaway yarn application from an earlier attempt. Kill it and check the yarn logs. Wait for it to finish and check the logs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139368/mapreduce-job-status-is-stuck-in-running-state   check this question please