# MapReduce job Status is stuck in Running State

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm trying to run Mapreduce program from Oozie (4.1.0).

But Its status is in RUNNING `state` and stuck at same status.

worklfow.xml

```xml
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="simple-Workflow">
   <start to="RunMapreduceJob" />
   <action name="RunMapreduceJob">
      <map-reduce>
         <job-tracker>localhost:8088</job-tracker>
         <name-node>hdfs://localhost:9000</name-node>
         <prepare>
            <delete path="hdfs://localhost:9000/dataoutput"/>
         </prepare>
         <configuration>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
               <value>default</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
               <value>DataDividerByUser.DataDividerMapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
               <value>DataDividerByUser.DataDividerReducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
               <value>/data</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
               <value>/dataoutput</value>
            </property>
         </configuration>
      </map-reduce>
      <ok to="end" />
      <error to="fail" />
   </action>
   <kill name="fail">
      <message>Mapreduce program Failed</message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=localhost:8088
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/Config
```

Job tracker is also running, here is a screen shot `https://prnt.sc/pbvb5i`

Error getting in JobInfo in OOzie url

```java
JA009: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "ec2-18-222-170-204.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/18.222.170.204"; destination host is: "localhost":8088;
```

May I know please what wrong is happeing ..?

Update:

Now all nodes are working fine `https://prnt.sc/pc4a7n`

Oozie logs

```java
hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/share/lib/lib_20190928171545/sqoop/oozie-sharelib-sqoop-4.1.0.jar, hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/share/l
ib/lib_20190928171545/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.3-hadoop100.jar]
2019-09-28 17:34:29,232  INFO Services:541 - SERVER[localhost] Initialized
2019-09-28 17:34:29,234  INFO Services:541 - SERVER[localhost] Running with JARs for Hadoop version [2.3.0]
2019-09-28 17:34:29,234  INFO Services:541 - SERVER[localhost] Oozie System ID [oozie-hdus] started!
2019-09-28 17:34:29,526  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:29,526  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:29,536  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:29,536  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:29,560  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:29,560  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:29,562  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:29,562  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:34:39,222  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:34:39,224  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running coordinator status se
rvice first instance
2019-09-28 17:34:39,222  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:34:39,519  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running bundle status service
 first instance
2019-09-28 17:34:39,521  INFO CoordMaterializeTriggerService$CoordMaterializeTriggerRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] 
APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] CoordMaterializeTriggerService - Curr Date= 2019-09-28T12:09Z, Num jobs to materialize = 0
2019-09-28 17:34:39,521  INFO CoordMaterializeTriggerService$CoordMaterializeTriggerRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] 
APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService]
2019-09-28 17:34:39,570  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:34:39,571  INFO PurgeXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] STARTED Purge to purge Wo
rkflow Jobs older than [30] days, Coordinator Jobs older than [7] days, and Bundlejobs older than [7] days.
2019-09-28 17:34:39,571  INFO PurgeXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] ENDED Purge deleted [0] w
orkflows, [0] coordinatorActions, [0] coordinators, [0] bundles
2019-09-28 17:34:39,639  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:35:39,571  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:35:39,572  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running coordinator status se
rvice from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:04Z
2019-09-28 17:35:39,616  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running bundle status service
 from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:04Z
2019-09-28 17:35:39,630  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:35:39,647  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:35:39,662  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:35:39,814  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[simple-Workflow] JOB[0000000-190928
171702728-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000000-190928171702728-oozie-hdus-W@RunMapreduceJob] Start action [0000000-190928171702728-oozie-hdus-W@RunMapr
educeJob] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2019-09-28 17:36:39,631  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:36:39,632  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running coordinator status se
rvice from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:05Z
2019-09-28 17:36:39,639  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running bundle status service
 from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:05Z
2019-09-28 17:36:39,643  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:36:39,663  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:36:39,685  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:37:39,644  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:37:39,645  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running coordinator status se
rvice from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:06Z
2019-09-28 17:37:39,656  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running bundle status service
 from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:06Z
2019-09-28 17:37:39,661  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:37:39,686  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:37:39,705  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:37:53,297  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,297  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,299  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,299  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,312  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,312  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,478  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,478  WARN AuthenticationFilter:341 - SERVER[localhost] AuthenticationToken ignored: AuthenticationToken expired
2019-09-28 17:37:53,631  WARN ParameterVerifier:544 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] The application does 
not define formal parameters in its XML definition
2019-09-28 17:37:53,893  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[simple-Workflow] JOB[0000000-190928
173423962-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] Start action [0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] with u
ser-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2019-09-28 17:37:53,895  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[simple-Workflow] JOB[0000000-190928
173423962-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] [***0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@:start:***]Action status=
DONE
2019-09-28 17:37:53,895  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[simple-Workflow] JOB[0000000-190928
173423962-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] [***0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@:start:***]Action updated
 in DB!
2019-09-28 17:37:54,128  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[simple-Workflow] JOB[0000000-190928
173423962-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@RunMapreduceJob] Start action [0000000-190928173423962-oozie-hdus-W@RunMapr
educeJob] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2019-09-28 17:38:39,662  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:38:39,663  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running coordinator status se
rvice from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:07Z
2019-09-28 17:38:39,671  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running bundle status service
 from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:07Z
2019-09-28 17:38:39,677  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:38:39,706  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:38:39,722  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:39:39,527  INFO CoordMaterializeTriggerService$CoordMaterializeTriggerRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] 
APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] CoordMaterializeTriggerService - Curr Date= 2019-09-28T12:14Z, Num jobs to materialize = 0
2019-09-28 17:39:39,528  INFO CoordMaterializeTriggerService$CoordMaterializeTriggerRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] 
APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService]
2019-09-28 17:39:39,679  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:39:39,680  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running coordinator status se
rvice from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:08Z
2019-09-28 17:39:39,687  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Running bundle status service
 from last instance time =  2019-09-28T12:08Z
2019-09-28 17:39:39,691  INFO StatusTransitService$StatusTransitRunnable:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache
.oozie.service.StatusTransitService]
2019-09-28 17:39:39,723  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
2019-09-28 17:39:39,743  INFO PauseTransitService:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] Released lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTra
nsitService]
```

But still Mapreduce is in Running PREP state. 
Error shows in the end like this

```java
JA009: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":8088;
```

Update -1
`hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000` output

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2019-09-28 19:44 hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/oozie-hdus
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2019-09-28 17:15 hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/share
```

Comment: Judging by the error, you could try replacing localhost in the namenode and jobtracker with ec2-18-222-170-204.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/18.222.170.204. However, I'm not very familiar with using Oozie on AWS.

Comment: @cricket_007, but am not using EMR ...! Set up everything on my local machine, single node cluster ...!

Comment: According to the screenshot, you have 0 healthy NodeManagers and 1 unhealthy one.

Please check out the logs for the nodemanager process and restart it

Comment: @cricket_007, I've fixed the healthy Nodemanager issue, not its working fine. But still job is stuck in running prep state. Not sure what's wrong...could you please check the update in question ..?

Comment: Go to the applications tab on the left, then look at the job being submitted to find out why it might be stuck

Comment: @cricket_007 https://prnt.sc/pc5ddt  Its doesnt say anything ..! Job suspended and got this error again JA009: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":8088;

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. Are you able to run the mapreduce outside of Oozie? Based on other questions, are you able to run `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000`? Which version of Hadoop are you using? The namenode is actually on port 8020 in certain versions

Comment: @cricket_007 yes am able to run outside oozie..manual run is running. Secondly when am doing hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000, I'cant see my input files, jar and workflow.xml..its just showing the output updated in question..!